# Company/Employee Community License

Tags: employee-community

How can we use company/employee community in our dev org or how can we get free licences for company/employee community.

Comment: if you are using standard dev org then see answer below,  if it is a sandbox linked to a production org then Salesforce needs to enable licences which can be replicated over to an existing sandbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Developer Org normally comes with a few licences for the Customer and Partner community. Go to Setup>Administer>Company Profile>Company Information and it will show the available licences.

My dev org has 3 Salesforce Platform licences, 5 Customer Community Login, 10 High Volume Customer Portal, 2 silver partner and 3 gold partner licences. I believe this can vary slightly depending on when a dev org is created as the licence types change over time as may Saleforce's policies on how many will be included in a dev org.

Saleforce licence types [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_available.htm&type=0&language=en_US) states that dev orgs do include Company Community User, but I think dev orgs created before that licence type was available will not include it. See details of customer community user below.

[image]
[image: Company Community User]